# SQL subquery invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, subquery

I am working on the below code recursively to same table but getting an error

`*Column 'checkinout.USERID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*`

`*Column 'checkinout.CHECKTIME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,checktime, 106) gateDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR,checktime, 106) gateIn
,(
    SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CH001.checktime, 108) 
    FROM checkinout CH001
    WHERE checktype ='I' 
        AND ch001.userid= mm001.userid   
        AND 
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR, CH001.checktime, 112) =CONVERT(VARCHAR, MM001.checktime, 112))
) timeIn

FROM  checkinout MM001
WHERE userid=@empid
```

Comment: This can't be you entire statement: I don't see `checkinout.userid` in the `SELECT` list.  For that matter, the only way you usually get those errors is if you have a `GROUP BY` clause or one of the aggregate-only functions, of which you have neither.  What RDBMS (obviously not MySQL), SQL Server?  Without an `ORDER BY`, that `TOP 1` clause has the potential to return an undefined row (I'm assuming the conditions should only get you one row, but...).  Comparing times that way is a good way to **not** use an index... what's the actual type of the column, and what values do you have?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse is right. If posted is the only code you have then it's not possible to have the given error as no aggregate function has been used. Also what's the problem statement for this query? Is it get the recent most checktime for a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,checktime, 106) gateDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR,checktime, 106) gateIn
,(
    SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CH001.checktime, 108) 
    FROM checkinout CH001
    WHERE checktype ='I' 
        AND ch001.userid= mm001.userid   
        AND 
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR, CH001.checktime, 112) =CONVERT(VARCHAR, MM001.checktime, 112))
) timeIn

FROM  checkinout MM001
WHERE userid=@empid
GROUP BY checkinout.USERID, checkinout.CHECKTIME
```

Comment: I get that's what the error is complaining about, but the provided statement wouldn't throw them in the first place.  Additionally, because the `SELECT` list is using non-aggregate functions on one of the columns, you'd have to use those same functions in the `GROUP BY` too (your answer will throw a syntax error).  Including a column in the grouping but not outputting it tends to make your results misterious, so your results would be off anyways.